# This value should not be blank

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know that could be a noob error, but I wasted a lot of time in this.

I have a entity that modified with a form. This is my entity:

```
class RetiroResiduo
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\SolicitudRetiroBundle\Entity\SolicitudRetiro")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="numeroSolicitudRet_id", onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="numeroSolicitudRet")
    */

    protected $numeroSolicitudRet;

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\ResiduoBundle\Entity\Residuo")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="siglaRepresentativa_id", onDelete="CASCADE",referencedColumnName="siglaRepresentativa")
    */

    protected $siglaRepresentativa;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\ResiduoBundle\Entity\Contenedor")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nombreContenedor_id", onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="nombreContenedor")
    */
    protected $nombreContenedor;

        ...
    }
```

This entity is handled with this form:

```
<?php
// src/Gestionresiudos/SolicitudRetiroBundle/Form/SolicitudRetiroType.php

namespace Gestionresiduos\SolicitudRetiroBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RetiroResiduoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('siglaRepresentativa')
            ->add('nombreContenedor')
            ->add('cantidadContenedores')
            ->add('peso')
            ->add('volumen')
            ->add('solicitar', 'submit')
            ->add('addotro', 'submit')
            ;

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Gestionresiduos\SolicitudRetiroBundle\Entity\RetiroResiduo',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'retiroresiduo';
    }
}
```

my action into my controller look like:

```
public function RetirarResiduoAction($idsol, Request $request)
    {
        $numSolRetiro = $idsol;
        $residuoARetirar = new RetiroResiduo();
        //echo gettype($residuoARetirar);
        $formulario = $this->createForm(new RetiroResiduoType(), $residuoARetirar); 
        $formulario->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formulario->isValid()) 
        {
        ....
        }
    ...
}
```

This is my form into view:

```
{{ form_start(formulario, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}})}}
        {{ form_errors(formulario)}}
        {{ form_rest(formulario) }}
        {{ form_end(formulario)}}
```

Finally I give you a print from the error to give my interface.

[image]

As you can see when I send my form doesn't enter into if(formulario->isvalid()). Obviously, I selected one option into choice. I saw similar questions but don't working for me. I need some advice or something that help me with this bug.

Note: I know that problem should be into my entity but I still don't see.
NOTE2: I'm using symfony2.3

Comment: Did you try with `'cascade_validation' => false` ?

Comment: @scoolnico I do it. works now. Do you know what could be the reason? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably due to the validation constraints used in `Residuo` entity.